# How to generate breadcrumb to dynamic asp menu in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, breadcrumbs, aspmenu

I have a dynamically generated menu (C#), like this:

```
MenuItem(string text, string value, string imageUrl, string navigateUrl, string target)

MenuItem AdminLevel1 = new MenuItem("Admin", "Admin");
MenuItem AdminPedidosRegisto = new MenuItem("Questions", "AdminQ");

NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Messages Received", "AdminMessagesR", "", "./Admin/Messages.ascx", "ContainerIframe"));

AdminPedidosRegisto.ChildItems.Add(new MenuItem("Pending", "AdminPending", "", "./Admin/Pedidos.ascx", "ContainerIframe"));`
```

Where `ContainerIframe` is the iframe's ID and `NavigationMenu` is the (asp:Menu)'s ID.

I want to add a breadcrumb to my page, but the menu isn't always the same.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could see you manage your menu items manually, you should do the same for breadcrumb items.

Just create a List breadCrumbItems on your master page and in each page you add the corresponding breadcrumb.

If your menu items are dynamically generated, use the same structure to generate your breadcrumbs.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? I never used asp menu control, neither automatic breadcrumb

Comment: Could you be more specific @MalachiteBR ?

Comment: @Hahn86, more specific than that would be possible only with the source code with me. I gave you an idea on how to solve your problem.